MAUI Application WinUI3 Windows window default title bar does not change with text size
I’m working on a MAUI application for Windows and I’m trying to set the top padding of a UI element so it does not overlap the titlebar. I’ve written a function to calculate the required padding on top, which I’ll provide below. The problem arises when I change the text size setting in Windows for accessibility reasons. While the default title bar of other applications adjusts correctly, the MAUI application’s title bar does not change in the same way. My function returns the correct height that matches the required padding for any default window other than the MAUI application.
My code for calculating the titlebar height
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetThemeSysSize(IntPtr hTheme, int iSizeId);
public const int SM_CXFIXEDFRAME = 7;
public const int SM_CYCAPTION = 4;

public int TitleBarHeight(){
    IntPtr hTheme = IntPtr.Zero; // Using the default theme of windows
    int titleBarHeight = GetThemeSysSize(hTheme, SM_CYCAPTION);
    int titleBarBorderSize = GetThemeSysSize(hTheme, SM_CXFIXEDFRAME);
    return requiredTitleBarPadding = titleBarHeight + titleBarBorderSize;
}


This function return 32 for normal text size and 51 on 225% Text Size setting which seem to match the default title bar height behavior.
If the text size is set to 100% the GitBash window I used as an example has the same title bar height as the test MAUI application.
100% Text Size
But when I set the text size to 225% the GitBash window title bar adjusts, but the test application title bar height seems to be unchanged.
225% Text Size
My question is if this is a settings issue or it is just not adjusting by default in MAUI / WinUI3? Do I have to create a custom titlebar for the windows version of the application to resolve this issue? I could not find a setting that disables the default behavior.
Thanks

The official document only mentioned that It will increase the size of the title bar to 48px when you include a searchbox or  a person-picture.

I see, but there is no additional content added to the title bar. My problem is that the MAUI window is not following the default behavior of any window. The increased text size effects the title bar height of any other application so the bigger letters can fit but the height is not changing for MAUI.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT So if I understand this correctly the MAUI title bar height is not effected by the windows text size setting if I don´t add anything custom right?

This issue cannnot be reproduced on winui. You may raise an issue on GitHub.

Thank you for checking and testing  on WinUI. I will create an issue

Thanks for your feedback. You may follow up the issue and get the latest updates.
